# React + Pinecone + OpenAI CORS error while upserting the embedded vectors into Pinecone Vector Database

Tags: reactjs, cors, openai-api, vector-database

I am using Pinecone vector database to store OpenAI embeddings for text and documents input in React framework.

```
    "use-client"
    import { loadQAStuffChain } from "langchain/chains";
    import { OpenAI } from "langchain/llms/openai";
    import { Document } from "langchain/document";
    import { OpenAIEmbeddings } from "langchain/embeddings/openai";
    import {PineconeStore} from "langchain/vectorstores/pinecone";
    import { PineconeClient } from "@pinecone-database/pinecone";
    import React from "react";

    export const pine = async () => {
      const embeddings = new OpenAIEmbeddings({ openAIApiKey: "******" });
      const model = new OpenAI({ openAIApiKey: "*******"});
      const chain = loadQAStuffChain(model);
    
    
      const docs = [
        new Document({ pageContent: "India is located in Asia." }),
        new Document({ pageContent: "India is surrounded by 3 seas and a mountain range." }),
      ];
    
    
      const pinecone = new PineconeClient();
      await pinecone.init({
           environment: "*****",
           apiKey: "******",
       });
    
     pinecone.projectName="1a65f5a"
    
     const index = pinecone.Index("pine");
     console.log(docs)

     const store = await PineconeStore.fromDocuments(docs, embeddings,{
          pineconeIndex: index,
          namespace: "pine1234"
      })
};
```

After implementing this code, the code worked till the `console.log(docs)` (a few code lines before the last). But it is showing the CORS error below while I am trying to store the embedded vectors in the Pinecone Database during the implementation of `PineconeStore.fromDocuments`

[image: CORS Upsert Error]

Comment: See the big note at the top of [this page](https://js.langchain.com/docs/modules/indexes/vector_stores/integrations/pinecone)... _"**Only available on Node.js**"_

Comment: Right. Got it. But does that mean that I can't use any other JS frameworks apart from Node.js. Because I have seen GitHub repos using Pinecone with React and Next JS. 
   
Thanks

Comment: @Phil And. Is it sure that the usage of React instead of Node causes the CORS error mentioned above?

Comment: It means you cannot run it in the client-side (browser). You may need to proxy requests through a Next.js API handler

Comment: @Phil Got it, so, I can create a proxy or NodeJS  server to handle this error and get the response in React. (The same code in NodeJS  is working, I just checked it)

Thanks

Comment: Recent update, https://support.pinecone.io/hc/en-us/articles/8764985175709-CORS-Issues. Pinecone can't be called from the front end directly using React.js.  We need to have a web server to route the API call to Pinecone.